# php email validation (filter_validate_email) Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, validation, email-validation

I know there are numerous questions about this however I just can not seem to pick the error with my coding. I know it is something simple but I can not see it.

I have to create a form which when it is submitted the data will be inputted into `MySQL` database however the data needs to be validated first. I have 2 issues with this, the first being my email validation is not working using: `(filter_var($email, filter_validate_email))`

The problem is that when I submit the form it returns true regardless of if the email is valid or not.
If I put `(!filter_var($email, filter_validate_email))` it `returns false` regardless of the input.

The second problem is that when loading the page it initially adds a blank entry into the SQL database and it adds entries that aren’t valid. i.e. if I don’t enter a name when the form is submitted the validation runs and I get the `error message “name is required”` but it still creates an entry in the table with a blank name.

I am using PHP version 5.3.27

This is for my tafe course i am doing however they are on holidays at the moment so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Coding from file 1:

```
<body>
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr;
$Name = $Address = $Phone = $Mobile = $Email="example@example.com";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

if (empty($_POST["Name"]))
{$nameErr = "Name is required"; }

else {$Name = test_input($_POST["Name"]);}

if (empty($_POST["Address"]))
 {$Address = "";}
else
 {$Address = test_input($_POST["Address"]);}

if (empty($_POST["Phone"]))
 {$Phone = "";}
else
 {$Phone = test_input($_POST["Phone"]);}

if (empty($_POST["Mobile"]))
 {$Mobile = "";}
else
 {$Mobile = test_input($_POST["Mobile"]);}  


if(filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
 echo"Valid Email";
 }
else{ 
echo "Not a Valid Email";    
}
echo phpinfo();
}

function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

?>

<form name="addcontact" method="post" action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>", "add-contact.php">

<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<caption> Add New Caption </caption>
<tr>
<td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" maxlenght="50" tabindex="1"/> <span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="Address">Address</label></td>
<td><textarea name="Address" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="Phone">Phone</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Phone" size="20" maxlenght="20" tabindex="3" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="Mobile">Mobile</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mobile" size="20" maxlenght="20" tabindex="4" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="Email">Email</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" size="30" maxlenght="50" tabindex="5" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan"2" align="center"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="6"/>      
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>

<?php 
include("add-contact.php");
?>


</body>
</html>`

And coding from file 2:


<body>
<?php 
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$Address = $_POST["Address"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$Mobile = $_POST["Mobile"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];


$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "webbm01");
if (!$dbc)
die ('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());


$db_selected = mysql_select_db("tafe", $dbc );
if (!$db_selected)
die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$qry
 = "INSERT INTO contacts (Name, Address, Phone, Mobile, Email) VALUES ('" . addslashes($Name) . "', '" . addslashes($Address) . "', '" . addslashes($Phone) . "', '" . addslashes($Mobile). "', '" . addslashes($Email) . "')";

$rst = mysql_query($qry, $dbc);

if ($rst)
{
echo "<b><font color='green'>The contact has been added.</font></b>";
}
else 
{
echo "<b><font color='red'>Error: ". mysql_error($dbc) . ". The contact could not be added.</font></b>";
}

mysql_free_result($rst);


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you are doing everything on one page ?

Comment: There are 2 pages. 1 with the form and validation and then one with the coding to add the data to sql

Comment: put insert query in this condition it will work only when you submit click `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{}`

Comment: sorry I am confused, I have that in my coding at the start but when I click submit the validation does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code for email validation etc :

```
<body> <?php

// define variables and set to empty values


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["Name"])) {$nameErr = "Name is required"; }else {$Name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Name"]);}

if (empty($_POST["Address"]))  {$Address = "";}else{$Address = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Address"]);}

if (empty($_POST["Phone"]))  {$Phone = "";}else {$Phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Phone"]);}

if (empty($_POST["Mobile"]))  {$Mobile = "";}else {$Mobile = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Mobile"]);}  


if(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){   echo"Valid Email";  }else{ echo "Not a Valid Email"; }

}

?>

<form name="addcontact" method="post" action= "<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

<table border="1" cellpadding="2"> <caption> Add New Caption </caption> <tr> <td><label for="Name">Name</label></td> <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" maxlenght="50" tabindex="1"/> <span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span> </td> </tr>

<tr> <td><label for="Address">Address</label></td> <td><textarea name="Address" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2"></textarea></td> </tr>

<tr> <td><label for="Phone">Phone</label></td> <td><input type="text" name="Phone" size="20" maxlenght="20" tabindex="3" /> </td> </tr>

<tr> <td><label for="Mobile">Mobile</label></td> <td><input type="text" name="Mobile" size="20" maxlenght="20" tabindex="4" /> </td> </tr> <tr> <td><label for="Email">Email</label></td> <td><input type="text" name="Email" size="30" maxlenght="50" tabindex="5" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan"2" align="center"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="6"/>       </td> </tr> </table> </form>

</body> </html>`
```

Comment: That code does not validate the email either. If I put in an email, it just refreshes the form and nothing is echo'ed

Comment: "123" and a valid Hotmail address, both produced the same result

Comment: Did you use all my code ? its working with me.This is php function and it's validate only emails.

Answer (score 0):

The validation should happen in the file:

> 'add-contact.php'

Since this is what the from action is calling on submit.

The initial validators are meaningless since the $_POST array is not initialized.

The reason for the empty SQL insert statement is because you decide to do:

```
include("add-contact.php");
```

In the first file and it is running without valid $_POST initialization on each load of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  line `include("add-contact.php");`

This will stop the blank insertion in the database.
Also remove the action

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
```

Just try `action="add-contact.php"`.
Email validation is working fine for me.

Comment: ok i'll remove that. thanks. So my exact coding works for you? that's strange. I am using php version 5.3.27 so I would think that I should be able to use the filter_validate_email function???

Comment: Yes you will be able to use that and that will work.. when you are already using the inbuilt function PHP SERVER SELF, then there is no use of giving something extra which makes it more complex..

Comment: If you want some regex for email validation in case the function is not working you can try this 
<code>
if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $Email)) {
return "Email address is invalid"; 
</code>
}

Comment: so if I can use it then how come the validation wont work for me? if I remove the include("add-contact.php") and just do action="add-contact.php" the validation still does not work, when i submit the form it just says "valid email" even if i put in an invalid email such as "123"

Comment: Are you passing the correct value in the variable $Email ?? It should be $_POST['Email'] .. In the code above you have written $Email="example@example.com" and this is a valid email. So may be you need to check that and make the $Email proper and dynamic.

Comment: I have it working now from Mahmood's code below. Perhaps because I had "$Email" rather than "$_POST[Email]", unsure but its working so all good. Thank you for your help.